# Reference livewire array element in conditional

Tags: arrays, forms, laravel-livewire

I have a form containing a couple of fields which are bound to array items. I need to make the 2nd input (textarea) disabled/readonly if the checked value of the first is set to one of them. How do I do that?

```
<div class="pt-8 flex items-center">
    <div>
        <input type="radio" value="pass" wire:model="questions.{{ $index }}.result">
        <label>
            Pass
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="radio" value="fail" wire:model="questions.{{ $index }}.result">
        <label>
            Fail
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

<textarea wire:model.defer="questions.{{ $index }}.failure_reason" />
```

All I'm trying to do is add a `disabled="{{ $questions.index.result == 'pass' }}"` condition on the textarea, but I'm getting `undefined constant index` error. Same with `disabled="{{ $questions.$index.result == 'pass' }}"`. How do I reference the result property of the specific array item in the conditional?

```
<textarea wire:model.defer="questions.{{ $index }}.failure_reason" disabled="{{ $questions.index.result == 'pass' }}" />
```

I originally tried breaking the question out into a separate child component (one for each question.) Then the result wasn't an array item and disabling as follows worked fine.

```
<textarea wire:model.defer="question.failure_reason" disabled="{{ $question.result == 'pass' }}" />
```

However, I then hit issues when submitting the parent. Nested forms...I didn't want the question stored before the parent model, passing an event to trigger the child model updates wasn't reliable, etc..

Thanks.